# Objective C - Problemas con textos en celda

Tags: objective-c, uitableviewcell

Estoy tratando de crear celdas con altura dinámica, con un solo label no tengo problema, sin embargo al colocar dos o más label dentro de mi celda corta parte de los label o en ciertos casos no lo muestra.

La altura está de este modo:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

// Calculo
if(!self.myCell) {
    self.myCell = [self.tabla dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DynamicTableViewCell"];
}

// Config
self.myCell.label.text = [_dataSource[indexPath.row] uppercaseString];
self.myCell.label2.text = [_dataSource[indexPath.row] uppercaseString];

// Layout
[self.myCell layoutIfNeeded];
[self.myCell setNeedsLayout];

// Altura
CGFloat height = [self.myCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingExpandedSize].height;

return height;
}
```

Adicionalmente, mis label tienen constrains en el Superview y un espacio entre ellos. Además su número de lineas está en 0 y su modo de ruptura (Line Break) es Word Wrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mismo te estas complicando mucho. Si tienes correctamente puestos los constraints y es capaz de dibujar la celda solo tienes que devolver UITableViewAutomaticDimension e implementar un método mas

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return  UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return  UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: Me funcionó de maravilla !! Sólo en una vista tengo problemas pero espero que sean mis constrains

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado. Podrias marcarla como respuesta valida